# Lower the amount of graphical objects, lowering the processing time - Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg, path

I am drawing a landscape in Inkscape and so far i have drawn, mountains, a river and several trees. The trees are groups of many subobjects, like branches and leaves. Since I copied the tree several times, I now have maybe like 1 or 2 thousand objects.

I am using a laptop with Dual Core processor and 4 GB RAM, but 2 of those are dedicated to the graphics card, so 2 left for general processing.

Is there a way or trick on how to lover the number of objects(without loosing quality) so that I can draw without Inkscape stuck for few moments, sometimes, minutes?

Should I just use some of those, "Difference" or "Union"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Union (or Combine) won't probably help you that much because you have a lot of nodes to render (but may help, I seldom have this many objects).

I'd try to put those trees to a locked layer ? It might help because Inkscape won't try to compute the underlying object and its path when you hover them

Answer (score 2):

Use clones (Edit > Clone). They do not need much own space so at least the storage need is lower.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not modifying the trees anymore, you could make a backup from theese trees, convert them to PNG while you are working on the rest of the image, and when you do not need to work anymore copy the vector files again.

It sucks I know.